# How to create custom schema with Corda Vault Extension

Tags: database-schema, corda

From Corda documents, it says we can have custom schema in Vault Extension.

However there is not much clarity for Vault Extension which should have ability to create/manage custom database schema pertaining to node vault database.

Are we going to publish API in feature release of Corda

Answer (score 3):

Inside flows, the node exposes a JDBC connection that allows you to write native custom SQL queries (as a vault extension). You can access this JDBC connection using `serviceHub.jdbcSession()`.

If your question is about how to write a custom schema then please see the existing [Corda Persistence API](https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html) docs.

You can then query that custom schema using the new Vault Query API - please see the existing [Corda Vault Query API][3] docs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an example to the above, here's a custom schema for the Yo! CorDapp. See `YoSchemaV1` below:

```
// State.
data class State(val origin: Party,
                 val target: Party,
                 val yo: String = "Yo!") : ContractState, QueryableState {
    override val participants get() = listOf(target)
    override val contract get() = Yo()
    override fun toString() = "${origin.name}: $yo"
    override fun supportedSchemas() = listOf(YoSchemaV1)
    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema) = YoSchemaV1.YoEntity(this)

    object YoSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(Yo.State::class.java, 1, listOf(YoEntity::class.java)) {
        @Entity @Table(name = "yos")
        class YoEntity(yo: State) : PersistentState() {
            @Column var origin: String = yo.origin.name.toString()
            @Column var target: String = yo.target.name.toString()
            @Column var yo: String = yo.yo
        }
    }
}
```

In short, your state object needs to implement `QueryableState`, as above.

The full CorDapp is available here: https://github.com/roger3cev/yo-cordapp

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Roger, before day of posting, i have created schema with using MappedSchema interface by looking core code of CashSchema.V1 :)  but then i was facing challenges to register the schema in plugin registry,

Comment: Hi Roger, i have implemented example just like Yo schema, but now i am going to test this then i am getting some serialization error. i have added serialization as well in node's plugin registry but then i got some stack overflow error, below is the stack trace

Comment: SerializationCustomization customization = new SerializationCustomization() {
            @Override
            public void addToWhitelist(Class<?> aClass) {
                //this.addToWhitelist(aClass);
                if(!aClass.isInstance(PersistentStateRef.class)) {
                    this.addToWhitelist(aClass);
                }
            }
        };
        customization.addToWhitelist(net.corda.core.schemas.PersistentStateRef.class); node.getPluginRegistries().get(0).customizeSerialization(customization);