# how to register Custom Schema and make it queryable in Corda?

Tags: corda

related issues (that didn't help me resolve the problem):

[How to create custom schema with Corda Vault Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083270/how-to-create-custom-schema-with-corda-vault-extension?s=2|88.2991)

[Error While Fetching Data from Corda Custom Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175392/error-while-fetching-data-from-corda-custom-tables?s=3|47.3921)

and a few others: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorda%5D+custom+schema

I'm experiencing an error, related to Custom Schema Registration (I think). When running a VaultQuery with criteria for the fields in my state schema, I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.template.schema.SharedItemSchemaV1$PersistentSharedItem

and if I add a default constructor, then:

> vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy - org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate entity:  : com.template.schema.SharedItemSchemaV1$PersistentSharedItem

The project is here: https://github.com/tradle/sharing-cordapp

If you run the Flow Tests, they should pass. If you replace this line
(https://github.com/tradle/sharing-cordapp/blob/master/cordapp/src/main/java/com/template/ResolveToIdentityFlow.java#L87) with the code below, and re-run the Flow Tests, you'll hit the exception I mentioned.

> QueryCriteria criteria = new VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
>             .and(new VaultCustomQueryCriteria(tmpIdCriteria));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with using a default constructor which passes `null` for every value. Using the following instead worked for me:

```
public PersistentSharedItem() {
    this("", "", "", "", 0L, UUID.randomUUID());
}
```

Additionally, when using custom vault queries, you must always reference the entity attributes rather than the state attributes, as all queries use the Hibernate entities which are registered and usable with our `NodeSchemaService`. So instead of doing:

```
linkField = SharedItemState.class.getDeclaredField("link");
```

You'd need to do:

```
linkField = SharedItemSchemaV1.PersistentSharedItem.class.getDeclaredField("link");
```

If you want to use your schemas in flow tests, you also need to register the custom schema on each mock node:

```
for (StartedNode<MockNetwork.MockNode> node : nodes.getPartyNodes()) {
    node.getInternals().registerCustomSchemas(
        ImmutableSet.of(new SharedItemSchemaV1())
    );
}
```

In the future, the registration of custom schemas is this way is likely to become automatic.

Comment: thanks joel, this resolved the issue to a degree. Tests now pass. However, I still get an error ("Please register the entity 'com.template.SharedItemState'") when I run queries via CordaRPCOps from the web api. I pushed the project (https://github.com/tradle/sharing-cordapp), you can repro the error by starting and running: "curl http://localhost:10007/api/share/item/abc". Thanks again for your help

Comment: joel, I pushed again to make it easier to repro. Start the nodes and run the Run RPC Client configuration

Comment: Edited post above. Looks like you also need to register the schemas you're going to use.

Comment: how do I register those custom schemas in my web api? Is there a way to do it via CordaRPCOps?

Comment: Hi Mark, trying to repro, but hitting that endpoint with curl gives me a 404?

Comment: hi joel, sorry, made some changes since then. Can you use the vquery branch? Also, just in case it's useful, I'm running it under the debugger in Intellij

Comment: Thanks, reproduced it. That isn't expected behaviour AFAIK. I'll look into it.

Comment: The problem is actually caused by not using an Entity attribute in your VaultCustomQuery.
The error message you are seeing kind of gives a hint but could be more informative: "Please register the entity 'com.template.SharedItemState'"
You should always reference attributes from the Contract State Entity attribute (not the Contract State attribute).
So, instead of: 
linkField = SharedItemState.class.getDeclaredField("link");
you should use:
linkField = SharedItemSchemaV1.PersistentSharedItem.class.getDeclaredField("link");

Comment: Thanks Jose, reflected in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue while doing vault in the flow from the shell of the node. The error message was

"[Node thread-1] vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy - 
Please register the entity 'com.template.IState'
See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistance.html#custom-schema-registration for more information {}"

I had created a schema for my state but was using the state class

```
Field iValue = IState.class.getDeclaredField("IValue");
```

Changing it to schema persistence class did the trick with :

```
Field iValue = ISchemaV1.PersistentI.class.getDeclaredField("IValue");
```