# How to register custom schema in flow unit tests in kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, corda

I am trying to write flow unit test cases for dummy corda app but I am getting an error related to **register custom schema entity** while running flow tests.

I got one link that has related issue but didn't solve my problem:
[how to register Custom Schema and make it queryable in Corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569909/how-to-register-custom-schema-and-make-it-queryable-in-corda)

Code snippet that I wrote for a flow unit test is the following :

```
class CreateOrganizationFlowTests : BaseOrganizationFlowTest() {


    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(listOf(findCordapp("com.deqode.flows"))))
        partyA = network.createPartyNode(CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"))
        partyB = network.createPartyNode(CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"))
        partyC = network.createPartyNode(CordaX500Name("PartyC", "London", "GB"))


        listOf(partyA, partyB, partyC).forEach {
            it.registerInitiatedFlow(CreateOrganizationFlow::class.java, CreateOrganizationFlowResponder::class.java)
            it.registerInitiatedFlow(CreateOrganizationFlowResponder::class.java,
                    CreateOrganizationFlowResponderTwo::class.java)
            it.registerInitiatedFlow(UpdateOrganizationFlow::class.java, UpdateOrganizationFlowResponder::class.java)
        }

        network.runNetwork()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        network.stopNodes()
    }

    @Test
    fun `dummy test` () {

        val createOrganizationFlow = getCreateOrganizationFlow()
        val future = partyA.startFlow(createOrganizationFlow)
        network.runNetwork()

        val orgState = future.getOrThrow()
    }

}
```

I am getting below error while running test cases for flows:

```
[INFO] 11:31:27,540 [Mock network] corda.flow. - Flow raised an error: 
                    Please register the entity 'com.deqode.schemas.PublicUserAccountInfoSchemaV1$PersistentPublicUserAccountInfo'
                    See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration for more information. Sending it to flow hospital to be triaged. {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=3bea2465-1ec1-48b2-af09-79174a0306b1, invocation_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, invocation_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, origin=Only For Testing, session_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, session_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, thread-id=99}
[INFO] 11:31:27,544 [Mock network] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Flow [3bea2465-1ec1-48b2-af09-79174a0306b1] admitted to hospital in state StateMachineState(checkpoint=Checkpoint(invocationContext=InvocationContext(origin=RPC(actor=Actor(id=Id(value=Only For Testing), serviceId=AuthServiceId(value=TEST), owningLegalIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB)), trace=Trace(invocationId=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, timestamp: 2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, entityType: Invocation, sessionId=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, timestamp: 2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, entityType: Session), actor=Actor(id=Id(value=Only For Testing), serviceId=AuthServiceId(value=TEST), owningLegalIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB), externalTrace=null, impersonatedActor=null), ourIdentity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, sessions={}, subFlowStack=[Initiating(flowClass=class com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow, classToInitiateWith=class com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow, flowInfo=FlowInfo(flowVersion=1, appName=<unknown>), subFlowVersion=CorDappFlow(platformVersion=5, corDappName=workflows-0.1, corDappHash=9119C835A091F4F22106371A9ED0CA0999941BEB43E5EB90EF9A042C22024645), isEnabledTimedFlow=false)], flowState=Unstarted(flowStart=Explicit, frozenFlowLogic=E0E08FC517028C46544A5DF98311A3B490F6D889EEFEAB51951F9A24A8A8F029), errorState=Clean, numberOfSuspends=0), flowLogic=com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow@491ef938, pendingDeduplicationHandlers=[], isFlowResumed=true, isTransactionTracked=false, isAnyCheckpointPersisted=true, isStartIdempotent=false, isRemoved=false, senderUUID=e89abebb-d675-42b9-9c98-6a5b30c8a5de) {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=3bea2465-1ec1-48b2-af09-79174a0306b1, invocation_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, invocation_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, origin=Only For Testing, session_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, session_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, thread-id=99}
[INFO] 11:31:27,546 [Mock network] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Error 1 of 1: {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=3bea2465-1ec1-48b2-af09-79174a0306b1, invocation_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, invocation_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, origin=Only For Testing, session_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, session_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, thread-id=99}
 net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: 
                    Please register the entity 'com.deqode.schemas.PublicUserAccountInfoSchemaV1$PersistentPublicUserAccountInfo'
                    See https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html#custom-schema-registration for more information
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.HibernateQueryCriteriaParser.parseCriteria(HibernateQueryCriteriaParser.kt:559) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$VaultCustomQueryCriteria.visit(QueryCriteria.kt:510) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria$VaultCustomQueryCriteria.visit(QueryCriteria.kt:494) ~[corda-core-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.HibernateQueryCriteriaParser.parse(HibernateQueryCriteriaParser.kt:569) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService$_queryBy$2.invoke(NodeVaultService.kt:606) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService$_queryBy$2.invoke(NodeVaultService.kt:54) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:235) ~[corda-node-api-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:214) ~[corda-node-api-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:220) ~[corda-node-api-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy(NodeVaultService.kt:587) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService._queryBy(NodeVaultService.kt:569) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at com.deqode.service.UserService.getAccountByEmail(UserService.kt:100) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.deqode.service.UserService.isEmailUnique(UserService.kt:84) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow.checkUniqueConstraints(CreateOrganizationFlow.kt:108) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow.call(CreateOrganizationFlow.kt:65) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.deqode.flows.organization.CreateOrganizationFlow.call(CreateOrganizationFlow.kt:31) ~[classes/:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:270) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:46) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.3.jar:?]
[INFO] 11:31:27,548 [Mock network] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital. - Flow error allowed to propagate {actor_id=Only For Testing, actor_owning_identity=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, actor_store_id=TEST, fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=3bea2465-1ec1-48b2-af09-79174a0306b1, invocation_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, invocation_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, origin=Only For Testing, session_id=880e7734-e55a-46a4-858c-03b78cdf6f9a, session_timestamp=2019-12-19T06:01:27.255Z, thread-id=99}
```

I found out that I need to register custom schemas for flow testing but I don't getting a way how to do that in kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MockNetwork scans for cordapps for given package names and loads it for testing. It looks like you are just loading the `flows` cordapp. You should try to give package name which where you defined the contract, state, and schema classes.

```
network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(listOf(
       findCordapp("com.deqode.contracts"),
       findCordapp("com.deqode.flows")))
)
```

Comment: yeah or directly add base package like findCordapp("com.deqode"), it will include other packages as well for example **services, schemas and states**, etc.